# Merge Map columns in to single column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to merge the rows having dictionary inside the pandas data frame in single row. The output should have latest key values of that columns with all the keys

here is the input dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[{'a': 1, 'c': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 4}], [{'a': 5, 'b': 6}, {'a': 7, 'b': 8}]], columns=list('AB'))
```

```
           A                     B
0   {'a': 1, 'c': 2}    {'a': 3, 'b': 4}
1   {'a': 5, 'b': 6}    {'a': 7, 'b': 8}
```

expected

```
           A                     B
0   {'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c': 2}    {'a': 7, 'b': 8}
```

Thanks

Comment: is it a must that you have a dataframe returned or is a dictionary okay?

Answer (score 2):

You can try `reduce` inside a `dict` comprehension:

```
from functools import reduce

d = {c: reduce(lambda x, y:  {**x, **y}, df[c]) for c in df}
d = pd.DataFrame([d.values()], columns=d.keys())
```

---

```
print(d)
                          A                 B
0  {'a': 5, 'c': 2, 'b': 6}  {'a': 7, 'b': 8}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will give you your expected df:

```
def consolidate_dicts(input_df):
    # Create consolidated dicts
    dicts = []
    for col in input_df.columns:
        dicts.append({k: v for d in input_df[col] for k, v in d.items()})

    # Replicate original DataFrame with 1 row
    return_df= pd.DataFrame([dicts], columns=input_df.columns)
    return return_df
```

Edit: The answer from [Shubham Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63830601/9806365) is way easier than mine